# Why can tangent lines be used to find the angle of intersection of two curves?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors, tangent-line

What is the logic behind using tangent lines to find the angle of intersection of two curves?

[For example](https://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Emalabika/teaching/ubc/fall08/math263/hw02_solution.pdf):

[image]

I can understand why you need to find the point of intersection, and I can understand why you use the dot product to find the angle, but I don't understand why they used tangent lines to $r1$ $r2$ respectively?

Comment: To answer your question with a question, what does "angle between two curves at a point of intersection" _mean_? :)

Comment: hmm, i'm having a hard time answering that without using the words to define themselves...but it's basically the angle formed by their(the two curves') intersection..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'll forgive my putting words in your mouth: To define (and measure) the angle of intersection between two curves at a point $p$ where the curves intersect, we should look at $p$ Really Closely, magnifying our viewing scale until the curves look like straight lines.

In other words, if the curves are regular (have tangent lines) at $p$, it's reasonable to *define* the angle at which they meet to be the angle between their tangent lines.